# How to get max row from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

[PA012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5lK9.png)
and
[FILA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCBBL.png)

I did some research and came up with the following code:

```
with cte AS (
 select *,
  DENSE_RANK() over (partition by idEtapa order by idFila DESC) as rn
 from tbl_PA012_ExtratoCNAB
 inner join tbl_Fila
 on idDado = idCNAB
 where idEtapa in (
  select idEtapa from tbl_Etapa where idSolution = 12
  ) and idCNAB = (select MAX(idCNAB) from tbl_PA012_ExtratoCNAB)
 )
select *
from cte
order by idfila,rn desc
```

But I wanted to retrieve only the last attempt of each step by getting:

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsjPH.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Also, if possible, please provide a minimal reproducible example. (So parts of the query that are not necessary to your question should be omitted). That way you make it easier for us to help you, and also make it easier for anyone else with the same problem to make use of your question.